# can an alternative migration framework be used with hasura?

Tags: hasura

**Is it possible to use a different migration framework for your relational database with hasura?**

I am seeing hasura has the ability to manage migrations as noted in the documentation [here](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/migrations-metadata-seeds/migrations-metadata-setup/).

We are using liquibase as the migration framework for all of our other projects and want to use hasura, but keep our existing migration framework (liquibase).

In the setup documentation already linked above, there's a prompt that asks if you want to initialize the project with metadata and migrations. Is it as simple as saying no here?:

```
? Initialize project with metadata & migrations from https://docs-demo.hasura.app ? Yes
```

*Can this be done or do you have to use the hasura migrations if you want to use hasura?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can manage your database migrations however you want to, and you have no obligation to use Hasura. Hasura's migrations are just a collection of `.sql` files that can be applied/revoked sequentially.

What is critically important is that you keep Hasura's [metadata](https://hasura.io/docs/latest/migrations-metadata-seeds/manage-metadata/) in sync with the database state.

For example, if you're tracking a database column in Hasura, and you use a SQL client to drop that column in your DB, Hasura's metadata (which describes the tables, columns, etc. that are exposed through the API) will be inconsistent with the database state. The proper way to manage a task like that is to either (1) use the Hasura console UI, (2) use the Hasura metadata HTTP API, or (3) manually edit and `apply` metadata with the Hasura CLI.

The task of keeping Hasura metadata in sync with DB state becomes non-trivial very quickly as you start to make use of features like "actions" and "events". You should run through some real-life migration scenarios with your current set up to get a sense of the challenges.